# The Java Eclipse Console dont show the correct French characteres

Tags: java, eclipse, character-encoding, french

I’m using Eclipse IDE 2022-09 (4.25.0) and when I print a French text like Périneau, the console return P�rineau.

example:

```
String str = "Périneau";
System.out.println(str);
```

console:

```
P�rineau
```

Is there something that I can do to have a good output?

Comment: It's under _Run Configurations > Common > Console Encoding_.  Switch to "UTF-8" option.

Comment: Also make sure the **Console font**, set on the **Colors and Fonts** preference page, supports those characters.

Comment: Hi Reilas, Your solution Worked. It worked with ISO-8859-1 but not with UTF-8. Thanks You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to switch to *"UTF-8"*.

[Common Tab (Help - Eclipse Platform)](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-launchconfiguration-commontab.htm?resultof=%22%72%75%6e%22%20%22%63%6f%6e%66%69%67%75%72%61%74%69%6f%6e%22%20%22%63%6f%6e%66%69%67%75%72%22%20%22%65%6e%63%6f%64%69%6e%67%22%20%22%65%6e%63%6f%64%22%20).

> *Encoding*
>
> Sets the encoding for the console allocated for this launch. If **Default** is selected the launch will inherit the current Text file encoding setting from the [Workspace preference page](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-9.htm). Or a different encoding can be selected for this launch.